# Windows 8.1 apps can't access my internet

Tags: windows-8.1

I have Windows 8.1 Pro. I have been using it for 2 years but I never noticed that Windows apps don't have access to the internet connection anymore. I can use internet for surfing, downloading and other stuff but native apps like Store, Windows Update e.t.c. don't work. It worked fine when it was newly installed. I must have messed up with something. I have attached some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

You can see Store, Windows Update etc don't have access to the internet. My Windows is genuine and is activated.

Basically, I want to upgrade to Windows 10 and it requires updates installed. I can't install the updates because of this issue. The updates remain stuck at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to the the update problem.  I also experienced it, I followed this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/305580/321990), from this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/305576/windows-update-doesnt-progress-beyond-0-kb-0) and I solved my problem:

> I've found that sometimes you just have to wait, but if it takes a
>   significantly long time try the following:
>
> - Click the start button and type in services.msc
> - Stop the Windows Update Service.
> - Delete the contents of the C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution folder
> - Start the Windows Update Service.
> - Try Windows Update again.

### Source

[Windows update doesn't progress beyond 0 KB 0%](https://superuser.com/questions/305576/windows-update-doesnt-progress-beyond-0-kb-0)

Comment: I can't delete all of the contents of `SoftwareDistribution` folder. It says it is open in other file or folder although I have stopped the Windows Update service. I am trying downloading a small update like of 157 KB but it is still stuck at 0%. Plus, the window becomes unresponsive.

Comment: check again if it's really stopped, it can start alone (that's what happened to me). So when it gives you the error - open the services and verify it's stopped. Maybe you'll have to do it more than one time of deleting-stopping.

Comment: Hey I got the Windows 10 App but not the way you suggested. It was a long process and kinda difficult. But, still I can't see that Windows 10 is being downloaded. It says that you have reserved Windows 10 but there's nothing you can do for now.

Comment: Ok, that's a good start. Now, you can do two things from what I've tested: You can try my first solution, with deleting the files of the update service, and then it will be forced to check for updates again, or try and run this command from cmd as admin: `wuauclt.exe /updatenow`

p.s. I haven't noticed you didn't had the win10 app, so what I suggested at the answer was to try and force the update itself.

Comment: Thanks for your support! I have Refreshed my windows 8 installation. Now, everything works fine. I downloaded Media Creation Tool; it downloaded Windows 10 and did some other stuff as well but my PC didn't get updated to Windows 10 lol IDK why :'(

Comment: Hope you did got it until now ;)