# Windows 7 update doesn't progress beyond 0 KB 0%

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have tried the answers in this question

[Windows update doesn't progress beyond 0 KB 0%](https://superuser.com/questions/305576/windows-update-doesnt-progress-beyond-0-kb-0)

I have all ready installed the Update `kb3102810`, `Installing and searching for updates is slow and high CPU usage occurs in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2`

I have waited about 45 minutes and it has gone no where.

`WindowsUpdate.log` latest lines in file.

```
2016-02-11  17:36:23:677     356    1374    DnldMgr ***********  DnldMgr: New download job [UpdateId = {CB2E949C-7B90-4826-9DB0-0E5FA8B3651A}.201]  ***********
2016-02-11  17:36:23:677     356    1374    DnldMgr   * Queueing update for download handler request generation.
2016-02-11  17:36:23:677     356    1374    DnldMgr Generating download request for update {CB2E949C-7B90-4826-9DB0-0E5FA8B3651A}.201
2016-02-11  17:36:23:724     356    1374    Handler Generating request for CBS update CB2E949C-7B90-4826-9DB0-0E5FA8B3651A in sandbox C:\windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\902a68569cfad0482255ed6e0f029c53
2016-02-11  17:36:23:724     356    1374    Handler Selected payload type is ptExpress
2016-02-11  17:36:23:740     356    1374    Handler Detected download state is dsHaveDownloadResponses
2016-02-11  17:36:24:052     356    1374    Handler Request generation for CBS update complete with hr=0x0 and pfResetSandbox=0 
2016-02-11  17:36:24:114     356    1374    DnldMgr ***********  DnldMgr: New download job [UpdateId = {CB2E949C-7B90-4826-9DB0-0E5FA8B3651A}.201]  ***********
2016-02-11  17:36:24:114     356    1374    DnldMgr   * All files for update were already downloaded and are valid.
2016-02-11  17:36:24:130     356    1368    DnldMgr BITS job {14558046-1C04-40F1-9F69-5F5ED05C967E} completed successfully
2016-02-11  17:36:24:301     356    1368    DnldMgr   Download job bytes total = 431847, bytes transferred = 77616
2016-02-11  17:36:24:301     356    1368    DnldMgr ***********  DnldMgr: New download job [UpdateId = {FF010B0B-353D-4561-BDF7-59A5D6E56D3A}.201]  ***********
2016-02-11  17:36:24:301     356    1368    DnldMgr   * Queueing update for download handler request generation.
2016-02-11  17:36:24:301     356    1368    DnldMgr Generating download request for update {FF010B0B-353D-4561-BDF7-59A5D6E56D3A}.201
2016-02-11  17:36:24:442     356    1368    Handler Generating request for CBS update FF010B0B-353D-4561-BDF7-59A5D6E56D3A in sandbox C:\windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\7c8467ad7aaf7387919d0296e8dfd0dc
2016-02-11  17:36:24:442     356    1368    Handler Selected payload type is ptExpress
2016-02-11  17:36:24:457     356    1368    Handler Detected download state is dsHaveDownloadResponses
2016-02-11  17:36:24:816     356    1368    Handler Request generation for CBS update complete with hr=0x0 and pfResetSandbox=0 
2016-02-11  17:36:24:910     356    1368    DnldMgr ***********  DnldMgr: New download job [UpdateId = {FF010B0B-353D-4561-BDF7-59A5D6E56D3A}.201]  ***********
2016-02-11  17:36:24:910     356    1368    DnldMgr   * All files for update were already downloaded and are valid.
```

Task Manager Process List.

[image]

[2 Hours of WindowsUpdateLogs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7g2kVcwh4m_dmo4Tm12M01jY1U/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: *"I have waited about 45 mints"* -- What unit of time is a *"mint"*?  You may have not waited long enough.  Give it two hours.

Comment: See my answer here...http://superuser.com/a/1022204

Comment: had to wait 4 hours. for it to start installing updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft released a WindowsUpdate Client Update to fix the slow Update searching/Installation.

**Installing and searching for updates is slow and high CPU usage occurs in Windows 7**
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102810

**Download:**
**32Bit:** http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=fcd6bf5d-f004-4ca3-aa7e-1de462b91dd0

**64Bit:** http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=4fe566bd-31b1-4413-8c4c-412b52533669

Try this Update and look if it speeds up the installation of Updates. Stop the WindowsUpdate service before you try to install the update, otherwise you also see a long delay. There is also a [newer WU client, but I have no idea what this update fixes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3135445).

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention i all ready installed update `kb3102810`

Comment: try the other update from February.

Comment: by bad. kb3135445 is the one i want.

Comment: the update from February. `kb3135445` i am unsure yet if it has made any difference been waiting for 45 minutes still no change, i just leave it over night see if. the updates are done then. if not i will have to reformat it.

Comment: new stuff is in the log file. uploaded 2 hours of logs to Google Drive.

Comment: had to wait 4 hours. for it to start installing updates. but i got them installed.

Answer (score -1):

Download the update `KB3135445`in link given below

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50797

Install this update to resolve issues in Windows.

you may have to restart your computer.

Comment: that update is all ready and installed. unsure yet if it has made any difference.