# Downloading Windows Updates takes forever

Tags: windows-7, updates

I noticed when doing a manual Windows Updates using Control Panel it finds the updates fast enough but after selecting updates I want to install and asking to install them takes forever to Download updates and no progress indicated, but if I click the start icon after some time it shows the updates are ready to install if I Shut Down the PC, indicated by the yellow Bang. No indication of what updates are ready to install either.

If I let the Windows update run on downloading, it will eventually download and install the selected updates but still no progress indicated, but takes hours. I see this behavior on some (4) my W7 PC's (7).

Its like the Windows Update screen does not refresh.

Any insight to this behavior or how to solve it?

Fully updated Windows 7 64bit prior to this months (Aug 2016) patch Tuesday.

Note: Home network, Fios with no other issues. Its wide spread on several computers and does it on any of them when I travel with those devices also, it is a windows update gui issue. Happens on Normal month to month updates.

[image]

This has nothing to do with "checking" for updates [as answered in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates) I answered this question myself but this is an entirely different issue and have found no solution so far.

Note:

**This issue does not happen anymore since MS started rolling out servicing stack updates. for Windows Update issues after a Clean install of W7 see my post over here>>>>>**[Windows 7 SP1 Windows Update stuck checking for updates](https://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates/1022204#1022204)

Comment: I believe it's substantially the same problem. Internal algorithms used by WU to decide what to do and when to do scale atrociously when the number of available updates or the number of applicable updates increases.

Comment: I believe the world is flat, prove it.....but I do agree on your hypothesis. Windows Update is borked and has been for a long time, regardless of the patches for it.

Comment: It's hard to prove much of anything because Microsoft isn't that interested in airing their dirty laundry in public. My conclusion is based on observations of the time these operations take and the number of available/applicable updates.

Comment: What bothers me is it works perfectly fine on some systems. It does it with just a few updates, Like I said my systems are up to date and happens with the monthly updates.

Comment: What progress does it make after using this tool? http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9830262

Comment: or, as answered by Ruairi Fullam, back in '11: ["Windows update doesn't progress beyond 0 KB 0%"](http://superuser.com/a/305580/609632), on which you actually commented

Comment: I have used all the tools, no change. Its a gui refesh issue, re read the question carefully, it is downloading them but the gui does not reflect this.

Comment: There are 2 parts to Windows Update, "searching for updates" and "Downloading Updates" mine is the second. You are wasting time here.

Comment: Hey hijo, show what in the `C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log` file to see any error in this file related to ur problem migo.

Comment: Windows Update uses BITS to transfer the files in the background.  Is there any chance that something is monopolizing your network connection?  Like @GambleNerd said, the recent part of the WindowsUpdate.log file may shed light on what's happening.

Comment: See [my answer here](http://superuser.com/a/935644/8672), and have you installed the [Convenience rollup update for Windows 7 SP1](http://www.howtogeek.com/255435/how-to-update-windows-7-all-at-once-with-microsofts-convenience-rollup/)?

Comment: To All, Please read my question carefully, it is actually downloading updates but takes forever to show it in the Windows Update screen, so this is not related to any answer I can find including what Pimp_Juice_IT has posted.

Comment: Moab -  While I understand exactly what you are saying, I would suggest to you to not overlook the obvious and eliminate those as potential solutions to your problem as while those may not be the exact same to your issue, they are very closely related so the processes I posted below shouldn't be overlooked for potential solutions to your issue. I also think it is important to disclose the log file as indicated as well; people can only guess otherwise. Please even though it may not "sound" related don't disregard the suggestions in my answer; the problem is related to Windows Updates regardless

Comment: @Moab: You have not answered if you have installed the Convenience rollup update for Windows 7 SP1.

Comment: @harrymc if the system is fully patched what good would that do.

Comment: So as I understand it, the problem can be fixed simply by closing the Windows Update cpl window and reopening it?

Comment: @Moab - You can have all updates installed but not have the cumulative update.  The fact some clients exhibit this problem indicates that this could be a possability.  In a very short amount of time, Microsoft is switching to monthly cumulative updates for Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 similar to what happens with Windows 10.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal where did I say that? no.

Comment: What are you using for DNS? If you're not using your ISP's DNS, try switching to that before running Windows Update.

Comment: DNS in the router is same for all PC's connected to it, some have this issue some do not, it is not DNS related, as I sated these same systems have this issue regardless to the network (router) they are connected to.

Comment: These issues have been fixed with Servicing Stack Updates from Microsoft.

Answer (score 14):

> **Downloading Windows Updates takes forever**

### Dice Roll. . .

I like all the methods listed here on [this MS KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2509997) as potential solutions to this problem. In particular **Method 10 thru Method 13** stick out *to me the most* that sound like solutions I've used in the past to resolve correlated problems even if not exactly the same.

I'll only quote the methods below I would not skip for sure if I were troubleshooting this issue but I wouldn't limit myself to just these or just this KB for that matter but these may be good starting points for potential solutions.

I also agree that seeing any applicable detail from the `%windir%\WindowsUpdate.log` would be helpful in troubleshooting this issue.

Lastly, I'd start troubleshooting and working this problem from one of the machines and ensure it's connected to a rather speedy Internet connection so in other words if you're traveling and connected to public network or a mobile wifi, just wait to ensure those factors don't play a role in the issue just in case.

> ### [Potential Resolution Methods](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2509997)
>
> ---
>
> ### Method 1: Run the Windows Update troubleshooter
>
> To do this, go to the [Windows Update
>   troubleshooter](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9830262).
>
> ---
>
> ### Method 4: Run the System Update Readiness tool (CheckSur.exe)
>
> Download and run the System Update Readiness tool. This tool runs a
>   one-time scan for inconsistencies that may prevent future servicing
>   operations. For more information about how to download and run the
>   CheckSur.exe tool, see the following article in the Microsoft
>   Knowledge Base:
>
> > Fix Windows corruption errors by using the DISM or System Update Readiness tool (https://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821)
>
> Try to install updates again.
>
> **Note** After you run the tool, the CheckSur.log file is saved in the following location:
>
> ```
> %systemroot%\logs\cbs
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ### Method 5: Run the System File Checker tool (SFC.exe)
>
> To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open an administrative Command Prompt window.
> 2. At the command prompt, type **sfc /scannow**, and then press **Enter**.
> 3. After the scan is finished, try to install updates again.
>
> ---
>
> ### Method 6: Reset the content of the Catroot2 folder
>
> To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open an administrative Command Prompt window.
> 2. Type the following commands, and press Enter after each command:
>
>    - **`net stop cryptsvc`**
>    - **`md %systemroot%\system32\catroot2.old`**
>    - **`xcopy %systemroot%\system32\catroot2 %systemroot%\system32\catroot2.old /s`**
> 3. Delete all contents of the catroot2 folder, but do not delete the catroot2 folder.
> 4. Type the following command, and then press Enter:
>
> > net start cryptsvc
>
> 5. Exit the Command Prompt window.
>
> ---
>
> ### Method 8: Register the Windows Update files
>
> To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open an administrative Command Prompt window.
> 2. At the command prompt, type the following command:
>
> > ```
> > REGSVR32 WUPS2.DLL /S
> > REGSVR32 WUPS.DLL /S
> > REGSVR32 WUAUENG.DLL /S
> > REGSVR32 WUAPI.DLL /S
> > REGSVR32 WUCLTUX.DLL /S
> > REGSVR32 WUWEBV.DLL /S
> > REGSVR32 JSCRIPT.DLL /S
> > REGSVR32 MSXML3.DLL /S
> > ```
>
> 3. Try to install updates again.
>
> ---
>
> ### Method 10: Rename the SoftwareDistribution folder
>
> To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open an administrative Command Prompt window.
> 2. Run the following commands, and press Enter after each command:
>
>    - **Net stop wuauserv**
>    - **cd %systemroot%**
>    - **Ren SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old**
>    - **Net start wuauserv**
> 3. Try to install updates again.
>
> **Important** The following issues occur when you use this method:
>
> - Updates that are currently downloaded but that have not yet been installed have to be downloaded again by using Windows Update or
>     Microsoft Update.
> - When you delete the Software Distribution folder, your download history is removed.
> - If you currently receive updates from Microsoft Update and from Windows Update, you will have to reselect this option from the Windows
>     Update website.
>
> **Note** If the issue is resolved and you can successfully download and install updates, you can safely delete the
>   SoftwareDistribution.old folder to recover disk space.
>
> ---
>
> ### Method 11: Clear the BITS queue of any current jobs
>
> To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open an administrative Command Prompt window.
> 2. At the command prompt, type the following commands, and press Enter after each command:
>
> > ```
> > Net stop bits
> > Net stop wuauserv
> > Ipconfig /flushdns
> > cd \documents and settings\all users\application data\microsoft\network\downloader
> > Del qmgr0.dat
> > Del qmgr1.dat
> > Net start bits
> > Net start wuauserv
> > ```
>
> **Note** After you complete these steps, the BITS queue is cleared.
>
> 3. Try to install updates again.
>
> ---
>
> ### Method 12: Rename Pending.xml
>
> To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open an administrative Command Prompt window.
> 2. At the command prompt, type the following command:
>
>    **takeown /f C:\Windows\winsxs\pending.xml**
> 3. Rename the c:\windows\winsxs\pending.xml path by using the following command:
>
>    **Ren c:\windows\winsxs\pending.xml pending.old**
>
> ---
>
> ### Method 13: Run Chkdsk on the Windows partition
>
> To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Open an administrative Command Prompt window.
> 2. At the command prompt, type the following command:
>
>    **`Chkdsk volume: /f /r`**
>
> <sub>[source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2509997)</sub>

Comment: Since this is being linked from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1349374/windows-10-update-stuck-in-initializing-status-internal-corpnet-required) fresh new Win10 update train-wreck, I'll note the Method 11 (BITS) download location in Win 10 is here: `c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Network\Downloader`

Answer (score 2):

If the fixes for Windows Update listed in the other answers have not
fixed your problem,  the slow updating might be caused by the way that Windows
Update works on the affected computers.

In [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/935644/8672) of mine, I have explained
that Windows Update constructs in memory a tree of all the updates which could
apply to a computer, then prunes it with a view to the updates already installed
on the computer, to finally arrive at the set of updates that need to be installed and the order of installation.

The time taken for this brute-force process is a function of the total number
of updates available for this platform, since the last service pack.
Every service pack sort of defines a new platform for which updates start
to accumulate anew. Also, Windows Update need to transfer large amounts of data
from the Microsoft servers who may be overburdened.

Windows 7 SP1 came out on February 22, 2011, more than 5 years ago, and since then
the number of updates has grown enormously. In addition, Microsoft's
Windows Update servers now give priority on bandwidth to Windows 10 clients.
So all in all, Windows 7 SP1 is left to suffer.

To solve this problem, Microsoft has lately released the
convenience rollup for Windows 7 SP1, which, exactly the same as a
service pack, serves as a starting platform for updates.
Installing it results in a much smaller
updates tree which is much faster to download and process,
since only updates posterior to it are considered rather than all updates since 2011.
Unfortunately, it is not available via Windows Update and has to be
downloaded and installed manually.

For more information on the convenience rollup for Windows 7 SP1, read
[Microsoft overhauls Windows 7 and 8.1 updating -- but don't call it a service pack](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3071737/microsoft-windows/microsoft-overhauls-windows-7-and-81-updating-but-dont-call-it-a-service-pack.html?token=%23tk.IFWNLE_nlt_infoworld_tech_microsoft_2016-05-18&idg_eid=daf30e86c221aa1a6e7994afe03ad0d9&utm_source=Sailthru&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=InfoWorld%20Windows%20Report%202016-05-18&utm_term=infoworld_tech_microsoft#tk.IFW_nlt_infoworld_tech_microsoft_2016-05-18).

This convenience rollup is the only way by which one can reduce the
Windows Update running time on Windows 7 SP1. Another one would be to
launch it on hours in which the Windows Update servers of Microsoft
have more available bandwidth (early morning or late night).

Admittedly, the problems you observe are a bit extreme, and might be related
to some inefficiency that relates to the particular setup of these computers.
I think that some combination of factors has enormously increased the time that
Windows Update takes to download and prune its update tree.
This might even be a Microsoft bug.
You might gain more information on the problem by watching Windows Update
while it is working, as regarding memory usage, network activity and disk access.

Installing the convenience rollup for Windows 7 SP1 is the only way I can think
of to cut this Gordian Knot of Windows Update on the affected computers.
However, it will probably stop working some time in the future, so has to be applied
quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off automatic Windows updates from the Control Panel and turn off the Windows Update service. Then, go to C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download and delete everything in the folder. Restart the Windows Update service. Finally, open the CLI, type `wuauclt.exe /updatenow`, and press "Enter." Try to download the patches again and see what happens.

Comment: Yep I know how to do all that and much more, I have tried everything but a clean install.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** a permanent fix but if there's a particular update you need asap and don't have time to sort out something permanent at the moment you can use.

https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/

You need to use IE. Do that then disable the Windows Update service.

Then sort out a permanent fix when you have the time.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: Firefox refuses to even connect to your link, says the web site isn't configured correctly.  You do say that IE is needed, but that means not everyone can access this.

Comment: @fixer1234; How does that mean not everyone can access it?  Every version of Windows has IE installed.

Comment: @WesSayeed, I couldn't access the link to look at this solution and forgot that the question is actually about Windows.  So you're right, at least the Windows users who haven't disabled or removed IE can access it.  BTW, just changing the user agent isn't sufficient to view the link from another browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try manually installing all missing updates using WSUS Offline, http://wsusoffline.net/

In the software you can choose your OS, download **ALL** updates for that version of windows, and then start the updater, and it will install all missing updates.

Comment: Does not answer the question but is a work around.

Comment: Maybe updating your system this way gets rid of the bug causing it. Windows update is just a piece of crap sometimes (sorry for the wording), so this could fix it. Why would this not be a solution in your eyes then?

Answer (score -1):

The "Download pending" could also be due to expired / damaged certificates.
Considering that Windows 7 and Windows 10 are pretty much suffering from similar decisions when looking at Windows Update, I'd like to contribute a further possible solution.

Just in case you want to rely on tools included in Windows, feel free to check the Event Log -> Application for "CertificateServicesClient-AutoEnrollment" with ID 64 and a criticality of "Warning".
Alternatively, you can get a detailed error code using the Windows Update Minitool, which is basically a 3rd party tool interfacing with Windows Update.
For me, both Windows Update and the Windows Store seemingly started downloading but got stuck at "Download pending" and would not continue or show an error code.
The Windows Update Minitool finally gave me two error codes, the important of them being:

- 0x80240022 (which turns out to be certificate related, i.e. the certificate expired or certificate chain broke)

The solution seems to be rather simple, if you are able to find a working manual.
[Kaspersky is offering a rather decent one over here](https://support.kaspersky.com/13727).
This is especially helpful, as the rootsupd.exe tool is rather difficult to find.
And despite Kaspersky telling you to get the certificate store backup from a working device, feel free to just get the [latest list of certificates](http://ctldl.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootstl.cab) from Microsoft.
For some reason, I was not able to use those certificates without rootsupd.exe - the certificate management applet would show the certificate list, but would deem it broken.
When I used the rootsupd.exe to extract and import the contents of authrootstl.cab, my Windows Update finally started working again.