# Win7 SP1 install always fails to code 8000ffff catastrophic failure, target state 7 (full logs available)

Tags: windows-7, service-pack

Win7 32bit  SP1 always fails to critical failure without a reasonable errorcode,  any tips what to do?  other updates are ok.

I have tried standalone SP1, it fails after running a hour or so, here is LOG from todays try to run it.

sfc/scannow  gives errors that its unable to fix, leaving a lot of pending renames.

I have executed MS system update readiness tool  - it did not help

EVENT SYSTEM LOG

```
Changes to an update(Service Pack for Microsoft Windows (KB976932)) failed during Service Pack installation.
    Identity:     Package_for_KB976932~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.1.1.17514
    Error Code:   0x8000ffff
    Target State: 7
```

Below is CBS.LOG file, the begin of 80mb file looks ok but the error is in the end of it;

```
2017-05-14 21:23:53, Info                  CBS    Appl: Package: Package_38_for_KB2773072~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.1.1.5, Update: 2773072-113_neutral_GDR, Applicable: Applicable, Disposition: Installed
2017-05-14 21:23:53, Info                  CBS    Plan: Package: Package_38_for_KB2773072~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.1.1.5, Update: 2773072-113_neutral_GDR, current: Staged, pending: Default, start: Installed, applicable: Installed, targeted: Installed, limit: Installed, selected: Default
2017-05-14 21:23:53, Info                  CBS    Perf: Resolve chain started.
2017-05-14 21:23:53, Info                  CSI    000001e8@2017/5/14:18:23:53.303 CSI Transaction @0x3f7828 initialized for deployment engine {d16d444c-56d8-11d5-882d-0080c847b195} with flags 00000002 and client id [80]"TI1.30592216_1341436901:2/Package_for_KB976932~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.1.1.17514"

2017-05-14 21:23:53, Info                  CSI    000001e9@2017/5/14:18:23:53.303 CSI Transaction @0x3f7828 destroyed
2017-05-14 21:23:53, Info                  CBS    Perf: Resolve chain complete.
2017-05-14 21:23:53, Info                  CBS    Perf: Stage chain started.
2017-05-14 21:23:53, Info                  CBS    Exec: Express package staging finished without any missing file to download.
2017-05-14 21:23:53, Info                  CBS    Perf: Stage chain complete.
2017-05-14 21:23:53, Info                  CBS    Reboot mark refs: 0
2017-05-14 21:23:53, Info                  CBS    Enabling LKG boot option
2017-05-14 21:23:53, Info                  CBS    Restored system sleep block state: 0x80000000
2017-05-14 21:23:53, Info                  CBS    Exec: Processing complete.  Session: 30592216_1341436901, Package: Package_for_KB976932~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.1.1.17514 [HRESULT = 0x00000000 - S_OK]
2017-05-14 21:23:55, Info                  CBS    Session: 30592216_1341436901 finalized. Reboot required: no [HRESULT = 0x00000000 - S_OK]
2017-05-14 21:23:56, Info                  CBS    Session: 30592223_1062534866 initialized by client SP Coordinater Engine.
2017-05-14 21:23:56, Error                 CBS    SPI: (CSPICbsClient::ChangeState:556)Failed changing package state to 7 hr=0x8000ffff
2017-05-14 21:23:56, Error                 CBS    SPI: (CSPCInstallTask::Execute:1010)Failed to install package with identity Package_for_KB976932~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.1.1.17514 hr=0x8000ffff
2017-05-14 21:23:56, Info                  CBS    SPI: Reporting Failed package event
2017-05-14 21:23:56, Info                  CBS    Session: 30592223_1062534866 finalized. Reboot required: no [HRESULT = 0x00000000 - S_OK]
2017-05-14 21:27:37, Info                  CBS    SPI: Deleting directory: C:\023f738a14ef127fcc0f4d\5167834f29da6e33322f\e88a012d9ad4e32862.  ret=0
2017-05-14 21:27:37, Error                 CBS    SPI: (CSPInstall::Install:1583)Failed executing Install task hr=0x8000ffff
2017-05-14 21:27:37, Info                  CBS    SPI: Ending SP Installation
2017-05-14 21:27:37, Error                 CBS    SPI: (PerformSPInstallation:833)Failed to install SP using UI hr=0x8000ffff
2017-05-14 21:27:37, Error                 CBS    SPI: (wmain:1105)Failed to perform SP installation hr=0x8000ffff
2017-05-14 21:27:37, Info                  CBS    SPI: Reporting Failed event
2017-05-14 21:33:55, Info                  CBS    Reboot mark refs incremented to: 1
2017-05-14 21:33:55, Info                  CBS    Scavenge: Starts
2017-05-14 21:33:55, Info                  CSI    000001ea@2017/5/14:18:33:55.882 CSI Transaction @0x3f8168 initialized for deployment engine {d16d444c-56d8-11d5-882d-0080c847b195} with flags 00000002 and client id [10]"TI6.0_0:0/"

2017-05-14 21:33:55, Info                  CBS    Scavenge: Begin CSI Store
2017-05-14 21:33:56, Info                  CSI    000001eb Performing 1 operations; 1 are not lock/unlock and follow:
  Scavenge (8): flags: 00000017
2017-05-14 21:33:56, Info                  CSI    000001ec Store coherency cookie matches last scavenge cookie, skipping scavenge.
2017-05-14 21:33:56, Info                  CSI    000001ed ICSITransaction::Commit calling IStorePendingTransaction::Apply - coldpatching=FALSE applyflags=7
2017-05-14 21:33:56, Info                  CSI    000001ee Creating NT transaction (seq 2), objectname [6]"(null)"
2017-05-14 21:33:56, Info                  CSI    000001ef Created NT transaction (seq 2) result 0x00000000, handle @0xe08
2017-05-14 21:33:56, Info                  CSI    000001f0@2017/5/14:18:33:56.508 CSI perf trace:
CSIPERF:TXCOMMIT;161081
2017-05-14 21:33:56, Info                  CBS    Scavenge: Completed, disposition: 0X1
2017-05-14 21:33:56, Info                  CSI    000001f1@2017/5/14:18:33:56.508 CSI Transaction @0x3f8168 destroyed
2017-05-14 21:33:56, Info                  CBS    Reboot mark refs: 0
2017-05-14 21:33:56, Info                  CBS    Idle processing thread terminated normally
2017-05-14 21:33:56, Info                  CBS    Ending the TrustedInstaller main loop.
2017-05-14 21:33:56, Info                  CBS    Starting TrustedInstaller finalization.
2017-05-14 21:33:56, Info                  CBS    Ending TrustedInstaller finalization.
```

I also analyzed inf/setupapi.app.log it has errs;

```
!!!  cpy: Store copy Not NT5 signed 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\usbport.inf_x86_neutral_36dcabb60af69b68\usbuhci.sys'
!!!  cpy: Error 160: One or more arguments are not correct.
!!!  cpy: Store copy Not NT5 signed 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\usbport.inf_x86_neutral_36dcabb60af69b68\usbport.sys'
!!!  cpy: Error 160: One or more arguments are not correct.
!!!  cpy: Store copy Not NT5 signed 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\usb.inf_x86_neutral_d30dae84172297e2\usbhub.sys'
!!!  cpy: Error 160: One or more arguments are not correct.
!!!  cpy: Store copy Not NT5 signed 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\usbport.inf_x86_neutral_36dcabb60af69b68\usbehci.sys'
!!!  cpy: Error 160: One or more arguments are not correct.
!!!  cpy: Store copy Not NT5 signed 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\usbport.inf_x86_neutral_36dcabb60af69b68\usbd.sys'
!!!  cpy: Error 160: One or more arguments are not correct.
!!!  cpy: Store copy Not NT5 signed 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\usbstor.inf_x86_neutral_9d88b35623781f49\USBSTOR.SYS'
!!!  cpy: Error 160: One or more arguments are not correct.
!!!  cpy: Store copy Not NT5 signed 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\wvpchbus.inf_x86_neutral_4081b3954d367047\vpchbus.sys'
!!!  cpy: Error 160: One or more arguments are not correct.
!!!  cpy: Store copy Not NT5 signed 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\wvpchbus.inf_x86_neutral_4081b3954d367047\vpchbuspipe.dll'
!!!  cpy: Error 160: One or more arguments are not correct.
!!!  cpy: Store copy Not NT5 signed 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\vpcusb.inf_x86_neutral_55a9e62c3e7d51a4\vpcusb.sys'
!!!  cpy: Error 160: One or more arguments are not correct.
!!!  cpy: Store copy Not NT5 signed 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\usbport.inf_x86_neutral_36dcabb60af69b68\usbohci.sys'
!!!  cpy: Error 160: One or more arguments are not correct.
!!!  cpy: Store copy Not NT5 signed 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\sffdisk.inf_x86_neutral_130f79da61a126bb\sffp_sd.sys'
!!!  cpy: Error 160: One or more arguments are not correct.
```

Comment: The recommendation would be a clean OS install, so don't ask us not to recommend it.

Comment: Well I have tens of application in this 5 years old secondary  pc,  so I need to figure out a fix.. :)

Comment: @Tomas Those applications simply can be reinstalled.  I agree, your installation is corrupt, and you need to install Windows 7 SP1 from an ISO; there a reason you have wait so long to install the SP?

Comment: Also you might try to restore your system from an image or restore point. Or try to use wsus-offline. http://download.wsusoffline.net/

Comment: Couple of posts I wanted to share in case you find a solution to resolve the issue so you can at least run the standalone SP1. I would not install SP1 from Windows Update and just try to get the issue resolved so the standalone installer will run check here: https://superuser.com/questions/1113553/downloading-windows-updates-takes-forever/1115225#1115225 and also check here: https://superuser.com/questions/993233/failed-to-configure-restart-loop-with-windows-7-updates/993243#993243

Comment: please remove hold, i have added detailed log file and cleaned the question

Answer (score 1):

Despite your plea for not recommending a clean windows install, I'm afraid we'll need to burst your bubble.

**You're probably best off reinstalling Windows 7, and using an SP1 install.**

This will ensure your computer is patched properly and cleanly, allowing for other Windows updates to install without issue, and allowing your 5 year old machine to hum a little more smoothly. Leaving your machine on an unpatched Windows 7 variant leaves you vulnerable to many of the exploits that have been fixed over the years as well.

Before wiping your machine, make sure you have access to your Windows 7 serial number so that you can easily reactivate your copy.

Comment: Thanks but I prefer to find a problem from my OS files and fix it manually

Comment: You're wasting your time. This is the easiest way.

Comment: @Tomas What are you really expecting to do here? Open up some DLL file and edit it yourself? You'll likely end up making things worse, resulting in needing a clean install anyway.

Comment: I was kind of looking for solution to find out the corrupted os  files e.g. 3rd party tool called SFCFIX.EXE should be able to do it

Comment: @Tomas If you have a solution, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From SP log files it was possible to find a row with string " error " - it was used to detect that IIS component had an issue and was giving errors,  I uninstalled IIS  and reinstalled SP,  the computer is ok now.

Comment: You should provide more information.