# Windows 10 - cannot open any Windows app, settings, updates

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, troubleshooting, windows-store

I've been using Windows 10 for something like 2 years already and everything was fine, but recently, around 3-4 weeks ago I noticed I couldn't open Calculator app (the pre-installed one from the Store). I clicked on its icon in Start menu and simply nothing happened.

Then I started investigating and searching. I found some articles on restoring Windows Store apps using some commands in PowerShell (described for instance [here](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/windows-10-calculator-not-working-solved/)). I got many errors during this fix trial:
[image]

and it didn't help.
Currently I cannot even open any "system place" from start menu like "Settings", "Troubleshooting" - I can find it in start menu, but nothing happens when clicking on it.

I've also tried this this [Microsoft's troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027498/windows-run-the-troubleshooter-for-windows-apps) which said it cleaned some cache of windows apps and the Store opened, but I still cannot access any apps like before.
Also when I tried to install some app in the Store, the download was started and was very slow (~100kb/s) and it closed itself after several seconds.

I'm also not able to open Windows Updates - when I find it in start menu and click "Check for updates..." nothing happens.

I scanned my PC with Avira and Malwarebytes - it found nothing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried in elevated prompt `sfc /scannow`?

Comment: Yes, I also tried this one and it didn't help. I'm running it once again now, it will take some time, but I don't think it will help.

Comment: I've jut run `sfc /scannow` and the outcome is: `Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.`

Comment: Well this person had the same problem and fixed it - https://www.wintips.org/fix-broken-store-apps-deployment-failed-0x80073cf6-merge-failure-0x80070003-problems-windows-10/ I'm sure there must be a less dramatic approach though.  You could try running wsreset or follow: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13976.how-to-troubleshoot-microsoft-account-issues.aspx

Comment: Check and test with some of the methods I listed here (https://superuser.com/questions/1113553/downloading-windows-updates-takes-forever/1115225#1115225)—yes, still applies to Windows 10. Simple enough to test and confirm since you are having an issue with Windows Updates as well. You might look over some of the stuff I mentioned here as well (https://superuser.com/questions/993233/failed-to-configure-restart-loop-with-windows-7-updates/993243#993243).

Comment: @HelpingHand - I've just made this in-place reinstallation of Windows and it seems to work. I have all my data kept and all my issues seem to be solved now. I'll publish my answer here when I'm sure it really works :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, create new user account on your PC and see if there is the same issue.

If not, repair your corrupted user profile:

http://windowsreport.com/corrupt-user-profile-windows-10/

Otherwise, it could be caused by system components.

Please try to repair your PC without losing anything:

How to Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html

Comment: I exactly did in-place reinstallation of Windows, just using this link https://www.wintips.org/fix-broken-store-apps-deployment-failed-0x80073cf6-merge-failure-0x80070003-problems-windows-10/ proposed by @HelpingHand in the comment above. For now it seems to work - all my data is restored and all issues disappeared ;) Finally!

Comment: @DawidSibinski Did you have to reinstall all your user-installed software?

Comment: @dr01 no, everything was just fine and installed after this reinstallation.