# Windows 10 Update stuck in Initializing Status - [Internal – Corpnet Required]

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1803

**Question:**

I am trying to update one of my Windows 10 operating system, but it has been stuck in Initializing status.

The update in question is: `[Internal – Corpnet Required] 2018-08 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1803 for x64-based Systems (KB4343909)`

[image: windows update stuck]

I tried to search for `[Internal – Corpnet Required]`, but there are no results. I'm not sure why Windows Update is stuck. The strange thing is, I was able to successfully install update (KB4343909) on my other Windows 10 machine.

Does anybody know what `[Internal – Corpnet Required]` is? And why it would be causing my windows 10 update to be stuck in Initializing status?

Here is the result of running `winver`:

[image: winver]

**Update:**

Running the Fresh Start utility seems to have fixed my issue with Windows Update.

[image: windows 10 update is fine now.]

**Update 2:**
After running the Fresh Start utility, I reinstalled software on Windows 10 such as `TeamViewer`, `Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition` and `SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition`. Afterwards, I am getting the same Windows 10 Update issue all over again.

[image: same problem again]

Comment: Can the machine access the corporate network? Also, have you tried downloading KB4343909 from http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/secu/2018/08/windows10.0-kb4343909-x64_f931af6d56797388715fe3b0d97569af7aebdae6.msu

Comment: I'm not on a corporate network. It is my home network and the Windows 10 is running as a guest OS under VirtualBox. I have 2 additional Windows 10 running under VirtualBox that are able to update just fine. I will try to download KB4343909 and report back with my findings.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - I ran the standalone windows update installer and it says `Security Update for Windows (KB343909) is already installed on this computer. However, Windows Update is still showing the updates as pending (same as above screenshot).

Comment: @kimbaudi - Have you performed a reboot?

Comment: `winver` will inidcate which build you are running which will indicated if you have KB4343909 installed or not.

Comment: @Ramhound - Yes, I rebooted many times and Windows Update screen looks the same as before. I believe I am on Windows 10 Version 1803 for x64-based systems. I'm not sure why my system is indicating that I have KB4343909 installed, but Windows Update is hanging in initializing phase to update KB4343909. The thing I really don't understand is `Internal - Corpnet Required]` since I'm not on a corporate network.

Comment: @kimbaudi - Could you supply the information I requested in the body your question by editing it?  1803 is the version of Windows 10, I am looking for the build, and I am **not** looking for which edition of Windows 10 you are using

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81727/discussion-between-kimbaudi-and-ramhound).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user ran the Fresh Install utility, which means their installation was wiped, which means this issue no longer exists and cannot be reproduced.  Furthermore, the problem was solved by running the utility, so any solution suggested in an answer cannot be verified.

Comment: @fixer1234 - I updated my question because running Fresh Install did not resolve the issue. After I installed software such as VS 2017 Community and SQL Server 2017 Dev Edition, Windows Update problem persists.

Comment: kimbaudi - See various things in this post to try to resolve: https://superuser.com/questions/1113553/downloading-windows-updates-takes-forever/1115225#1115225 You might see if that helps and allows it to move forward but it not if you get to the step again and after completing the `Ren c:\windows\winsxs\pending.xml pending.old` then try installing the standalone installer again and see if it allows you to proceed after you perform that per the steps I outlined in that post.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT - I followed Method 10 from the link you provided and it solved the Windows Update issue I was having. It was the same method that was suggested to me earlier today by harrymc. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When having problems with Windows Update, here are a few possible
actions:

- Run PC Settings, Update & Security, Troubleshoot, and choose Windows Update
- Run Microsoft's
  [Windows Update Troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027322/windows-update-troubleshooter)
- [sfc /scannow](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-sfc-command-run-windows-10-a.html) - check Windows integrity.
- After resetting Windows Update as in the first point above, rename
  `C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download` as explained in
  [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/53274/8672)
  and reboot. If this doesn't help, redo again but rename instead
  `C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution` and reboot.

Comment: I already tried running Windows Update Troubleshooter by going to Settings -> Update & Security -> Windows Update. However, it just resets the Windows Update and when I click 'Check for Update' button, it shows the same screenshot that I posted.

Comment: After resetting Windows Update, rename `C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download` as explained in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/53274/8672) and reboot. If this doesn't help, reset again and execute again this procedure but rename instead `C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution` and reboot.

Comment: I ran into this issue again after running Fresh Install. So I ran `sfc /scannow` as admin user and there was no issue. So then I renamed `C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download` and Windows Update issue is resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One of my machines at home had the same issue.

**In brief**

I executed the following steps to solve the issue.

Step 1: Reboot in Safe Mode with Networking

Step 2: Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Windows Update > Run the troubleshooter

Step 3: Apply fixes

Step 4: Reboot (start windows normally)

Step 5: Set the correct time zone (make sure your machine has the correct time zone)

Step 6: Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update (if its downloading updates, **let it finish**. The update with indication `[Internal – Corpnet Required]` should have a link below it `Retry`. Click `Retry` when the update service has finish installing all other updates.

Comment: Running the troubleshooter in safe mode returns "Troubleshooting couldn't identify the problem".

Comment: This problem appeared to me last night while I was formating a computer at home. I remember that on step 3 while troubleshooter wizard was applying the fixes, it was displaying some progress messages. One of those messages was `rebuilding updates database` (it took about 4-5 minutes for the fixes to apply). I have 2 more windows 10 machines at home but none of them had this issue. It's really weird. The aforementioned steps was the solution in my case, so I wrote them down. The only thing I want to ask you, you were running the troubleshooter in `Safe Mode with Networking` ?

Comment: Step 1: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode

Answer (score -1):

Tried above method (safe mode etc) and it didnt work, 
Just spoke with Microsoft, this issue can only be fixed by reinstalling Windows, need to create NEW USB media via media creation tool April 2018 edition as it has newer updates imbedded.

For some reason, the update tasks in services.msc are being stopped when this "Internal - Corpnet" update tries initializing.
If you go to services.msc you will see BITS stopped. The Microsoft support live help changed this via remote access and it still didnt fix the issue so he recommended a new media creation install.

Download latest Windows 10 media creation tool (USB media creation also available) here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10

Edited: The new install did not work :(
Back on the phone to Microsoft.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tool? I'm having this same issue and I just reinstalled windows less than 24 hours ago using MediaCreationTool1803 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10.

Comment: no worries at all, glad to help....
https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10

Comment: It looks like there are some less traumatic fixes in other answers that may work in some cases.  You aren't clear on what may have been ruled out on your system before MS recommended reinstalling.  Also, the MS support people have a vested interest in solving your problem quickly rather than by the least destructive method.  This information is good to know, but people may want to try other things first, and save the big hammer in case the others don't work.

Comment: Yes, thats true however sometimes "Less destructive" methods can often be less successful in the long run.

Comment: I seriously have doubts the **only** way to do this issue is a nuke your windows install.  I have about 5 different solutions but the author wiped their system so none of them can be tested.

Comment: I still have a few systems experiencing the same error, before I go ahead and re-format with new W10 I am happy to run some checks if you like

Comment: Well here we go, reinstalled on first machine, performed first lot of updates, restarted, went to updates and there is the stupid Internal Corpnet error again (stalling on initializing), thanks Microsoft support lol

Comment: @BradGoBigOne - I can also confirm that Fresh Install did not fix the issue for me. Once I reinstalled software such as VS 2017 Community and SQL Server 2017 Dev Edition, I'm running into the same problem with Microsoft Update.

Comment: Just got off the phone with Microsoft, They used my newly created USB media and ran the setup.exe (within windows), then selected the option to install Windows (not the download and update option), apparantely its installing all updates, wow, looks like its not a lengthy task to install w10 on all of my new machines with this current version of W10 crated via the media creation tool