# Windows Updates won't install: "download error 0x800f0922"

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Good morning. For several weeks now, most of my Windows Updates have failed to install on my Windows 10 HP all-in-one. The current update, *2021-12 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 21H1 for x64-based Systems (KB5008212)*, is throwing up error message "download error 0x800f0922".

Every time I restart my computer, it attempts installation again, fails, reboots automatically and attempts installation *again*, fails, cleans itself up and then, finally, lets me log in. This cycle can take up to 20 minutes or so.

There are more than 700GB free on my system. Until about November, I never had any problems installing Windows Updates. I've not changed anything about my system or my internet connection so I don't know what can have gone wrong.

Things I've tried:

- Troubleshooting the Windows Update system
- Disabling firewall
- Manually downloading the update
- Safe mode
- DISM restore
- Pausing updates to see if the problem will resolve itself (I've now run out of pauses and don't have this option any more)
- Ensuring that .NET features are enabled
- Setting App Readiness to automatic

Can anyone recommend anything?

Comment: Did you try *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Additional troubleshooters > Windows Update > Run the troubleshooter*?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by 'Troubleshooting the Windows Update system'

Comment: Try [more suggestions](https://superuser.com/a/1349398/8672). (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: The first thing I would try is to install [KB5008212](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5008212)

Comment: Please [run](https://superuser.com/a/1579031/529800) the following from an Admin terminal _while connected to the internet **(must be run in the order listed)**_: `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup ; Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth ; Sfc /ScanNow` _(Windows 10 defaults to powershell; if using cmd, change `;` to `&&`)_